# How to save a decimal number with Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a Symfony2.3 project and I need an `input number` that lets me save the value with decimals and samples the arrows. With the following code I can show the decimals but then only the whole part is saved.

**Entity**

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="horas", type="decimal", scale=1)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $hours;
```

**FormType**

```
 ->add('hours','integer', array('required' => true,'attr' => array('min' => 15,'max' => 40,'step' => 0.5)))
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: By the way, Symfony 2.3 is no longer maintained. 2.8 is the current LTS release.

Comment: I know thanks, but I started the final project with that version and I prefer to finish it before I modify the version that I'm just going to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store a floating point value in a decimal field, you must first decide how many digits you need before the point, and how many after. For example, your field could look like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=3, scale=1)
 * @Assert\Range(min=15, max=40)
 */
private $hours;
```

In a `decimal` field, the `precision` is always the total number of digits, while `scale` denotes the length of the fraction part. In the example above, the decimal field could store values between 0 and 99, while one digit after the point would be stored.

Note that Doctrine will represent the field as string, so if you retrieve the entity, the value of the field would be `"20.5"` (i.e. a string). You must manually convert the value to a float again. This can be done in the getter for the field:

```
public function getHours()
{
    return (float) $this->hours;
}
```

Comment: Hello @lxg, thanks for the reply. I need to save data form 20.5, where the total number of hours a person works, for example that case would be 20 hours and a half. What would he have to do in this case?

Comment: Ok, I see. I have modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: You have modified what you have told me, but still save the value without a correct fractional part. For the case of 20.5 storage 20.0 remains. Could it be by the formtype I indicated?

Comment: Sorry @lxg, I was using FormData to send the data from ajax, because I also had to save an image file, and seeing that it was not saved well I added that value to the FormData and I used it in php with setHours () and finally Keep well. I do not know where the problem would be, but anyway thanks for the clarification above.